# Cannot edit after setting WPF DataGridCell ControlTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datagridcell

I'm customizing a WPF `DataGridCell` style, but once I've done this double click to edit no longer works. I've also tried to manually call `myDataGrid.BeginEdit`, but nothing seems to happen. This is code similar to what I have:

```
<Style x:Key="MyCell" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
         <Setter.Value>
             <ControlTemplate>
                 <Border>
                     <TextBlock />
                 </Border>
             </ControlTemplate>
         </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I assume the problem is that because I'm overriding the ControlTemplate, an editor no longer exists? If that's the case, is their a way I can sort this to use the default editor?

Comment: If you aren't overriding the cell edit template then it should work fine, also make sure `CanUserEditRows` is set to `True` on your Datagrid. I have to see your Datagrid's XAML to further understand your problem.

Comment: Why are you changing the `ControlTemplate` in the first place? What are you trying to achieve? Usually you can do everything you need in a `DataGrid` using `DataTemplate`s.

Comment: @KeithStein I'm using a subclassed TextBlock which sets different foreground colours for individual words in the content string. I couldn't figure out how to do that without replacing the `ControlTemplate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm using a subclassed `TextBlock` which sets different foreground colours for individual words in the content string. I couldn't figure out how to do that without replacing the ControlTemplate.

Instead of creating a custom `ControlTemplate` , you should create a custom column type and override the `GenerateElement` method to return an instance of your custom type:

```
public class CustomColumn : DataGridTextColumn
{
    protected override FrameworkElement GenerateElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
    {
        return new YourCustomTextBlock();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you should avoid overriding `ControlTemplate`s unless you really need to make substantial changes to the functionality or layout of a control (or if your building your own). You can usually do what you need with `DataTemplate`s instead, which keep the underlying control intact, but customize the way your data is displayed.

For the `DataGrid`, there is a special type of column type meant just for this: [`DataGridTemplateColumn`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn). Here's a quick example of how to use it:

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <!--This is used when the cell is being displayed normally-->
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomePropertyOfYourRow}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <!--This is used when the cell is being edited (e.g. after double-click)-->
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding SomePropertyOfYourRow}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

You can easily put your custom `TextBlock` into the `CellTemplate` and it will be use to display the contents of that cell.